# Replace every n linebreak to tabs in a file

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++, lines, ultraedit

is it possible to replace every 4 Lines the Break to a Tab in UE or NPP with a regex search/replace?

File before:

```
    #12
    ab
    cde
    ef
    #34
    ghij
    ijk
    kl
    #5678
    uv
    w
    xyz
...
```

should be after replace

```
#12 ^t ab ^t cde ^t ef
#34 ^t ghij  ^t ijk ^t kl
#5678 ^t uv ^t w  ^t xyz
```

Comment: Are the lines like "ab" always only characters? Or are there might numbers? Or: Is the new first column always starting with #?

Comment: why not doing it with notepad++ macro?

Comment: you can achieve above in two steps:

1.Find # and replace with \r\n# 
2.Find \s+ and replace with \t

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way to do the job:

Find what: `(.+)\R(.+)\R(.+)\R(.+\R)?`
Replace with: `$1\t$2\t$3\t$4`

Check `Regular Expression`
DON'T check `dot matches newline`
and click `Replace All`.

**Explanation:**

```
(.+)\R   : Capture in group 1 everything until a line break (excluded)
(.+)\R   : Capture in group 2 everything until a line break (excluded)
(.+)\R   : Capture in group 3 everything until a line break (excluded)
(.+\R)?  : Capture in group 4 everything until a line break (included), optional
```

`\R` stands for any kind of linebreak (ie. `\r` or `\n` or `\r\n`)

Comment: @user3214779: Is it OK?

Comment: hi, sorry i am busy the last days and thanks for your solution. it works, except: there are some empty lines without any chars and two or more linebreaks togehter [crlf][crlf]

Comment: @gsxr1300: Just replace `.+` with `.*`.

Answer (score 2):

`[\n\r](?!#)` Will do
 and replace by `\t`

It will replace crlf if not followed by a # by tab when using windows encoding.
`(?!#)` is a negative lookahead which exclude any \n or \r followed by a # (on next line)

Beware it will leave a space before the tabs, if you really wish only tab between each field you may have to change encoding to have only \n or \r (linux or mac).

Comment: @Surinderツ As far as I understood, #123 has not to be moved, just the following lines. Replacing the carriage return by tab (unless the last one) makes lines starting by #123. I edited to explain the regex (forgot it, sorry)